# Title in custom item display template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, search-results

I created a custom item display template for my search center:

```
....
    <span class="title">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Title=#_</span>
....
```

The goal is to show the title of each document in the document library. The strange thing is that it isn't returning a title for every document. Even when the doc types and document library are exactly the same.

[image: Sharepoint Search]

Comment: Are you sure that the documents have titles? Files always get their filenames stored in the name column in a document library, while the title field is optional until changed to mandatory manually.

Comment: @user19952 All documents have titles. It seems to be related to something else. See my comment under Dylans answer,

Comment: is the title field added in header, please check once?
                                                                     
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the OOB Document content type, `Name` is the required field that is the name of the file, `Title` is optional.  Is it possible that the `Title` field was never filled out for the documents in question?

[image]

I believe the internal name of the `Name` column is `FleLeafRef`, so if you change your display template to use

```
<span class="title">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef=#_</span>
```

you should start seeing the behavior you expect.  (Of course, remember to add `FileLeafRef` to the section at the top of the display template that tells it what metadata to bring in.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that the Sharepoint field ctx.CurrentItem.Title is not always looking to the title field of your item, but also to a title field within a Word document. This is not what I want. It should always look to the SP field. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: If you are trying to make it always look at the SP `Title` field and not also look at the internal "Title" metadata of a Word document, the only way I can think of offhand is to maybe create your own managed property that looks at the SP `Title` field only.  However, `Title` is still optional on the Document content type, so if you want to ensure that you always show the file name, you should use `FileLeafRef`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this is the Search Schema. 
Go to Site Settings -> Search Schema
Put "title" in the filter box
Click on Title and go to the Mapped Crawled Properties and make "Title" the top item , not MetadataExtractorTitle.